# Problemas com imagens HTML enviadas para email

Tags: html, email, gmail, outlook

Fiz vários testes usando uma imagem com caminho absoluto. Dentro da intranet funciona perfeitamente, porem na extranet (GMAIL/OUTLOOK) não funciona de jeito nenhum. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: @LuisAlmeida Sim, elas estão disponiveis, a imagem foi ajustada e publicada em produção, estou usando o caminho absoluto, porém as vezes aparece sem formatação no gmail/outlook, as vezes não aparece. Já tentei usar css inline e muito mais, não dá certo! Engraçado que no email corporativo funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: em algumlugar do teu codigo estas a usar tables?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida sim, < table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" background="https://exemplo.com/imagem_examplo.jpg" witdh="550" height="750">

Lembrando que, a imagem quando aparece no GMAIL/OUTLOOK, é desconfigurada.

Comment: @LuísAlmeida Ja coloquei o background na <td> e também apareceu desconfigurada.

Comment: Editei a resposta que tinha dado anteriormente. Por favor verifica.

Comment: Verificando aqui!

Comment: @LuísAlmeida verifiquei, apareceu como antes, a imagem cortada. Lembrando que a imagem é em caminho absoluto. Antes o problema ja existia, a imagem era alocada no diretório raiz do site, e a mesma foi publicada em produção com as mesmas dimensões para ver se resolvia essa problema de visualização em email externos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica onde estás a ir buscar as imagens. Se essas imagens estão disponiveis externamente...

As imagens para estarem acessiveis têm de estar em algum local disponivel na internet. exemplo: ftp...

Coloca assim:

```
<table style="font-size:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" background="exemplo.com/imagem_examplo.jpg"; witdh="550" height="750">
```